# How to compare the current pathname and route in next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-router-dom

I am currently migrating a project which was created with [creat-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) to a [next.js](https://nextjs.org/) project.

One thing that I faced into is to migrate the [matchPath](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/matchPath) function from [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) to somewhat next.js function comparing the current pathname and a kind of passed `href` route name so as to realize and select a current nav item.

```
import { useLocation, matchPath } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavBar = ({ item, pathname }) => {
  const open = matchPath(pathname, {
    path: item.href,
    exact: false
  });
  ...
}
```

I was able to get the current `pathname` using [next/router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object), but after that, I have no idea how to compare them.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const NavBar = () => {
  const { pathname } = useRouter();

  ...
}
```

In this case, how to figure it out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, NextJS doesn't have that (!).

Here's a function (and tests) that I'm using.
https://gist.github.com/tomfa/f925366cd036bb0d4af5bbd8397c84ae

Comment: Thanks for this — surprising that next doesn't offer this. I made a suggestion on your gist.

Answer (score -3):

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const NavBar = () => {
  const { pathname } = useRouter();
  const parts = pathname.split('/');
  const match = parts[parts.length - 1];
  const open = match === 'blogs' //or whatever
  ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this case, `blogs/` or `blogs?id=1` should be the same to `blogs`. Does it work like that?

Comment: Yes, it should be `blogs` in both cases. Always can test it out real quick